# swift for loop with sleep

Tags: ios, swift4

I have a Swift 4 ios app that displays a random message and photo when a button is pressed. This works fine but I want to create an endless loop to display the random message/photo when the button is pressed. I have tried several ways to accomplish this but none have worked. It seems the labels and imageviews will not update until the main thread has completed. Below is my current method of trying this, which is not even an endless loop but still have the same issue. The print statements show in the debug window but the label and imageview is never updated.

```
@IBAction func loveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    nextNote()

}


func nextNote() {

    for number in 1...1000 {

        print("number is \(number)")
        randomPhoto = Int(arc4random_uniform(18))

        if randomPhoto == lastRandomPhoto {
            randomPhoto = Int(arc4random_uniform(18))
        }

        photoDisplay.image = UIImage(named: photoArray[randomPhoto])

        lastRandomPhoto = randomPhoto

        randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(14))

        if randomNum == lastRandomNum {
            randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(14))
        }

        loveNote.text = msgArray[randomNum]
        lastRandomNum = randomNum
        print("end of loop before sleep")
        sleep(6)
        print("end of sleep")
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `Timer` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `Timer` instead...

```
var timer: Timer!

func nextNote() {
    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 6.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.setPhoto), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func setPhoto() {

    randomPhoto = Int(arc4random_uniform(18))

    if randomPhoto == lastRandomPhoto {
        randomPhoto = Int(arc4random_uniform(18))
    }

    photoDisplay.image = UIImage(named: photoArray[randomPhoto])

    lastRandomPhoto = randomPhoto

    randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(14))

    if randomNum == lastRandomNum {
        randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(14))
    }

    loveNote.text = msgArray[randomNum]
    lastRandomNum = randomNum
}

func somethingToEndTheLoop() {
    self.timer.invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `DispatchQueue`. Using it you won't need to create a heavy timer object, also you will be sure that your code runs on main thread when it's free from other tasks.

```
@IBAction func loveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    nextNote()
}   

func nextNote() {
    randomPhoto = Int(arc4random_uniform(18))

    if randomPhoto == lastRandomPhoto {
        randomPhoto = Int(arc4random_uniform(18))
    }

    photoDisplay.image = UIImage(named: photoArray[randomPhoto])

    lastRandomPhoto = randomPhoto

    randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(14))

    if randomNum == lastRandomNum {
        randomNum = Int(arc4random_uniform(14))
    }

    loveNote.text = msgArray[randomNum]
    lastRandomNum = randomNum

    let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(6)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
        nextNote()
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using DispatchQueue, it has the same issue. If I am just executing the code once and the main thread ends it works but so does sleep in that case. Neither work when  doing it within a loop.