# Xcode- Image View Not Changing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview

I am trying to update a UIImageView using a for loop, however, the image only shows up on the last iteration of the loop. The code is intended to display a QR code, wait 4 seconds, then display a different QR code, however it only shows the last QR code.

```
            for record in 1...importedrecords.count-3 {
            let qrCode = importedrecords[record][0] + " " + importedrecords[record][1] + " " + importedrecords[record][7]
            print("QR Code is: " + qrCode)

            let data = qrCode.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
            filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "InputMessage")

            let ciImage = filter?.outputImage

            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
            let transformImage = ciImage?.transformed(by: transform)

            let image = UIImage(ciImage: transformImage!)
            self.myImageView.image = image

            do {
                sleep(4)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since you are doing some UI related work I would suggest using  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter and instead of using a loop create a function and then call it recursively from inside DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter. Answer by Ivan on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525676/swift-for-loop-with-sleep might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `Timer` for this. Using `sleep` is not recommended, especially on the main thread, since it stops all the work being done on the thread.

```
    var timer: Timer?
    var recordIndex = 0
    var importedRecords = [[String]]()

    // Call this when you want to start updating
    func startUpdate() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector:#selector(updateQR), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    // Call this when you want to stop and reset updating
    func stopUpdate() {
        timer?.invalidate()
        recordIndex = 0
    }

    @objc
    func updateQR() {
        let qrCode = importedRecords[recordIndex][0] + " " + importedRecords[recordIndex][1] + " " + importedRecords[recordIndex][7]
        print("QR Code is: " + qrCode)

        let data = qrCode.data(using: .ascii, allowLossyConversion: false)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
        filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "InputMessage")

        let ciImage = filter?.outputImage
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 10)
        let transformImage = ciImage?.transformed(by: transform)

        let image = UIImage(ciImage: transformImage!)
        myImageView.image = image

        // This will prevent out of bounds crash
        if recordIndex < importedRecords.count {
            recordIndex += 1
        } else {
            stopUpdate()
        }
    }
```